# Electron doesnt execute https call to local spring server, curl works

Tags: javascript, java, typescript, electron

I'm simply trying to connect to a local Spring configured with SSL / TLS 1.2.

Context (Server): Server is built with Spring, logs when creating a request via curl. Also requires a certificate from the client (X.509 certificate based authentication)

Client (CURL, command-line):
Works fine!

Client (Electron):
When the code below gets executed nothing happens. No requests are being made to the spring (nothing logs), nor is any error occuring. Nothing. Electron is such a drag to debug..

Code:

```
let options = {
                hostname: 'localhost',
                port: 8443,
                path: '/',
                cert: fs.readFileSync(global.relativePaths.config + 'client.crt'),
                key: fs.readFileSync(global.relativePaths.config + 'clientprivate.key'),
                passphrase: '[phrase_here]',
                rejectUnauthorized: false,
                requestCert: true
            };
            let request = https.request(options);
            request.on('error', () => {
                console.log("Error!");
            })
```

Also, this is just localhost, hence the rejectUnauthorized - I'm working with self-signed certificates until ready for production. :)

Thank you in advance. :)

EDIT:
using the test-code on the wiki (call to github) outputs with no problem.. what could it be?...
also, im doing this on the main process (not on the renderer)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `http-client` library like `[axios][1]`. axios is a promise-based HTTP client for the browser and node.js. It worths giving a try to most used libraries like axios, it's simple to use. If the issue still persists, try setting the `User-Agent` header in your request.

Comment: Why would I want to use an external dependency when there are two native modules available to me? I'm not planning to do any extraordinary networking, so unfortunately the first option falls off - I've set the User-Agent, it still doesn't work out. (I'm trying to work with the already existing modules) :/

Comment: sorry, can't edit the comment above, i didnt mean to sound hostile - just wanted to point out that i'd rather not use axios :) none the less, i've fixed it ty